# Oracle APEX: calling an inline popup from a link column on a classic report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am attempting to call javascript from a link column, that will open an inline popup by setting target URL for that column to:

```
javascript:$s("P3_ITEM","#COLUMN1#");openModal("MY_INLINE_POPUP");
```

and I am getting a javascript error: `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Coding Duchess. Is this problem solved?

Comment: nope, never got resolved

Comment: Hi Coding Duchess, did my answer below help?

Comment: Hi Dan. Not sure because you posed your answer a few days ago and this question has been abandoned back in February

Comment: I see, I will not worry about it anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you do not set the template of the region which you are trying to call as modal/inline dialog..

You need to change the template of your region "MY_INLINE_POPUP" to Inline Dialog and you can do this by going to Region Settings -> Appearance -> Template and then select Inline Dialog...

One additional tip: while creating an inline dialog, you also need to take care of one more Region setting and i.e. Region Layout. Inside Region Layout, the position must be Inline Dialogs..

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to reproduce the issue using the Inline Dialog template, however, I got the error with the Inline Popup template. Here are some steps that should help address the issue with either template...

1. Change the column's **Type** from **Link** to **Plain Text**.
2. Navigate to apex.oracle.com/ut > Reference > Button Builder. Use the button builder to build a button that you like, you can even style it like a link if you prefer that look over a button. Copy the HTML in the **Entire Markup** field and paste it in the **HTML Expression** field of the column. Here's an example:

   ```
   <button type="button" class="t-Button t-Button--link">My Button</button>
   ```
3. Add two things to the markup from the previous step: 1) any column values needed as "data-" attributes and 2) a class to target in a Dynamic Action (I'll use my-custom-class). You're example needed the value from COLUMN1, so it would look like this after:

   ```
   <button type="button" data-column1="#COLUMN1#" class="t-Button t-Button--link my-custom-class">My Button</button>
   ```
4. Create a new Dynamic Action. For the Dynamic Action, set **Event** to **Click**, **Selection Type** to **jQuery Selector**, **jQuery Selector** to **.my-custom-class** (from the HTML above), and **Event Scope** to **Dynamic** (to keep things working if the report refreshes). For the Action created by default, set **Type** to **Execute JavaScript Code**. Enter the following code in the **Code** field:

   ```
   $button = $(this.triggeringElement);
   $s('P3_ITEM', $button.data('column1'));
   ```

   That will transfer the column value to the item as you were doing.
5. Add an additional action to the Dynamic Action. Set **Type** to **Open Region** and then select the correct region to open.

That should do it. I couldn't find the `openModal` function documented anywhere. It may not be maintained anymore. The Dynamic Actions **Open Region** and **Close Region** are probably the best choices now. One could use the jQuery UI dialog API, but I'd advise against it.

For more info, check out this blog post from John Snyders: https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2019/12/23/all-the-things-that-pop-up/ There's a demo app there that you can download and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a popup region then use this:

```
$("#POPUP_REGION_ID).popup("open");
```