# Oracle apex Button within row to call region as inline popup dialog

Tags: oracle, dialog, popup, inline, apex

I am using apex 20.2.  I have an interactive report, and, following [Dan McGhan's post from March 9, 2020 to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60346468/oracle-apex-calling-an-inline-popup-from-a-link-column-on-a-classic-report) , I have a button that opens a region on the page from each row.  That's great - but...

How/where do I specify which region to open, based on a value in the row? Meaning, I want a different region to open, based on a value in the row.

OR

How do I pass a value from the master grid, to the region?  That way, I can put sub-regions in the region that will open as an Inline DIalog, and only the pertinent region will appear.

Thank you